# X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff on Internet Explorer

Tags: .htaccess, internet-explorer, amazon-s3, content-type, content-encoding

After setting

`Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"`

, images being served from Amazon S3 on Internet Explorer do not load any more. What could be the root cause of this issue? Thanks.

Comment: You didn't set the `Content-Type` on the files, or you set it incorrectly, perhaps?